# What's a difference between unary and binary operator parsing in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm learning some techniques to make a very simple Haskell parser that serves to calculation consistence (addition, subtraction and other trivial operations). Library I use is Parsec. Although I've got some comprehension on binary calculation, it seems to be tough to me if I try to make a unary operator function, for example that of negation (~). There is a code snippet I use to implement parsing for multiplication:

```
import Text.Parsec hiding(digit)
import Data.Functor

type Parser a = Parsec String () a

digit :: Parser Char
digit = oneOf ['0'..'9']

number :: Parser Integer
number = read <$> many1 digit

applyMany :: a -> [a -> a] -> a
applyMany x [] = x
applyMany x (h:t) = applyMany (h x) t  


multiplication :: Parser Integer
multiplication = do
    lhv <- number
        spaces
        char '*'
        spaces
        rhv <- number
        return $ lhv * rhv
```

Switching to an unary operation, my code for factorial as follows:

```
fact :: Parser Integer
fact = do
    spaces
    char '!'
    rhv <- number
    spaces
    return $ factorial rhv


factorial :: Parser Integer -> Parser Integer
factorial n
    | n == 0 || n == 1 = 1
    | otherwise = n * factorial (n-1)
```

And once module is getting loaded, an error message appears just like that:

```
 Couldn't match type `Integer'
                 with `ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Integer'
  Expected type: Parser Integer
    Actual type: Integer
```

Confusingly, it's a hard case for me to realize what's wrong with my comprehension about unary ops comparing them to binary ones. Hoping any help to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`factorial` doesn't define a parser; it computes a factorial. The type should just be `Integer -> Integer`, not `Parser Integer -> Parser Integer`.